# A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script

Tags: angular

Error I'm getting in chrome dev:
[image: Error I'm getting in chrome dev]

After using `ng serve` I continuously get these error and I've researched hard on how to clear them but no avail although the app seems to work well, I just need to clean up those errors

Answer (score 7):

On the page where these errors are displayed, go to Dev Tools -> Applications -> Clear storage -> Clear site data. The Service Workers has one feature, it really will cache the information. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 6):

Chrome=>Dev Tools=>Application=>Service Workers=>Update on reload (selected)

[More details](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/446)

Comment: It not work for me

Comment: Doesn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 3):

For me in react application, I was getting 404 when `sw.js` file was placed inside `src` directoy, once I moved the `sw.js` file inside public directory, the issue got resolved

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that there is a pending subscription to a service worker for which the current application has no source code (hence the 404).

This means that it is very likely it's not your pages'fault.

Anyway I understand that red lines can be annoying when debuging...

A possible shortcut solution is to unsubscribe by hand from the browser inspect page console:

To have a look of how many registrations are there:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations();
```

To remove the first registration:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistrations().then((r)=>{r[0].unregister()})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

the service worker JS file which you are registering does not exist.

It might be that you are giving service-worker.js while registering, and it is working fine at home page, because this file exists there. but on another page, some inner directory or htaccess rewrite or controller path, service-worker.js not exist.

so give full path to js file: http://www.example.com/service-worker.js

means, instead of this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
```

You should write:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://www.example.com/service-worker.js')
```

this way in all your directories or controllers, this path is fixed and file exists and you will not see that 404 error in console.

Answer (score 0):

Give production: false, in Angular Projects only it's working.
environment.prod.ts => production: false,
environment.ts => production: false,